# Message is not passing to Kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm working on a simple application using spring boot and Kafka to save an object to a Kafka topic and then there is a consumer that will listen and add that record to a in memory database. After below configuration both Kafka and spring boot is working but API call to Kafka will hang for a while and there won't be any messages in Kafka topic as well.

I followed the below tutorial

https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/

But i changed a my Service a little bit.

```
package com.dilshan.shoppingcart.cart;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

@Service
public class ShoppingService {
    private static final String TOPIC = "users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, ShoppingCart> kafkaTemplate;

    private ShoppingCartRepository cartRepository;

    public void publish(ShoppingCart cart) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, cart);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "group_id")
    public void subscribe(ShoppingCart cart) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello-"+cart.getId());
        cartRepository.save(cart);

    }

}
```

this is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
server.port=8080
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group_id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal=false
```

This is the controller i'm using to access the kafka methods.

```
package com.dilshan.shoppingcart.cart;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ShoppingCartController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingService shoppingService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/shoppingcart")
    private ResponseEntity<ShoppingCart> selectProducts( @RequestBody ShoppingCart cart) {
        shoppingService.publish(cart);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

And below logs are continuously showing in application log.

```
2020-02-18 19:22:12.951[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6986[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#0-0-C-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2m2020-02-18 19:22:13.958[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6986[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#0-0-C-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2m2020-02-18 19:22:15.115[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6986[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#0-0-C-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2m2020-02-18 19:22:16.272[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6986[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntainer#0-0-C-1][0;39m [36morg.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group_id] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: Are your kafka brokers up and running?

Comment: Please make sure that you have kafka up and running

Comment: I think my kafka is running.I checked it using the terminal. Please refer the log below.                    
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z_Hx5K9DU-0QtLQRZOa3PMiyrkr0T-AR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't install kafka separately in my pc. I just followed the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka broker, sometimes it's called Kafka server, should be running on your pc or on a remote machine.

Please check this link
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

First, you need to run Zookeeper and Kafka broker
And then you can send messages with your application.